# Overlapping divs on IE < 9 - working fine on IE9 and other browsers

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9, overlapping

I've developed an website (by the way, for a young and very creative artist :) but I'm having a problem with overlapping divs.

It can be seen at http://www.anaaragao.com/galeria/

If you press "portfolio", the categories listing will appear misaligned. Also, if one selects one of those categories, the post images will appear on a single column instead on a grid.

It doesn't happen in IE9, Firefox, Chrome or Safari. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Meanwhile I'm keeping searching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You disabled the context menu? Why would you do that?

Comment: Sorry. Re-enabled it. I know it's not a very friendly thing to do but it was a direct request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look at your js code, but it seems that you created a wrong style when it's loaded in IE 8. Here is the first ul column in your source code.

```
<ul class="mcol2 li_cont1" style="width: 293px; cssfloat: left;">
```

Change style value from `"width: 293px; cssfloat: left;"` to `"width: 293px; float: left;"`, then it will fix the layout issue.

Comment: Not solved yet, but thank you for pointing in the right direction. I have jQuery code that creates that style, which is: jQuery(this).css({cssFloat:'left', width:''+col_Width+'px'});  .It seems IE 8 and IE 7 cant understand the cssFloat command. But If I change it from "cssFloat" to "Float" in the jQuery code, then Safari will show the exact same problem that IE 8 does now! So this must be it...

Comment: Use jQuery(this).css({'float':'left', 'width':col_Width+'px'});

Comment: Otherwise, jQuery(this).css('float','left'); ... otherwise try latest version of jQuery

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem. Now it is working fine as it should be. All the best!